# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError error while writing a code in java vs code

Tags: java, oop, visual-studio-code

I was writing a code in java in vscode's ide and was getting java.lang.NoSuchMethodError even after doing everything right according to me. Please someone tell me what am I doing wrong.

code :

```
class person {
    String name ; 
    int age ; 

    person() {
        
    }
    
    person(String name , int age) { // [ PARAMETERIZED CONSTRUCTOR ]. 
        this.name = name; // " this.name " is name of the object.
        this.age = age; // " this.age " is age of the object.
    } 
}

public class parameterizedConst {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        person p1 = new person(" nobil " , 20); 

        person p2 = new person(" yaman " , 18); 

        System.out.println(p1.age + " " + p1.name);
        System.out.println(p2.age + " " + p2.name);
}
}
```

the following is the error i am getting in the terminal window:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: introduction.inputFromScanner.loops.nestedLoopsPatterns.logicalOperators.OOPS.person.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;I)V
        at introduction.inputFromScanner.loops.nestedLoopsPatterns.logicalOperators.OOPS.parameterizedConst.main(parameterizedConst.java:20)        
PS D:\eclipse-workspace\Yaman Java>
```

Please help me identify the problem.

Comment: This may happen if an incorrect versions of class files are used. Try recompiling everything and run again.

P.S. you should take a look at Java Naming Standards
https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html

Comment: [There is no problem with code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaRmV.png) Can you show your project structure (or folder structure)? In addition, I see that your terminal directory contains spaces. It is best to modify the folder name to ensure that the script path is all English and no special symbols and spaces.

Comment: I don't know what do you mean by incorrect versions of class files. I tried recompiling everything and running again but the same errors shows

Comment: So, please provide more details about your environment.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor for `person` is not public so it can not be used from another class. Make it public.